# Where does Intl.NumberFormat support come from in node.js?

Tags: node.js

In my browser console:

```
> Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf('it')
["it"]
```

In node on my computer:

```
> Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf('it')
[]
```

In node on my coworkers computer:

```
> Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf('it')
["it"]
```

Same versions of node 4.5.0

Where is the Intl.NumberFormat support supposed to come from?  What do you have to build to get it included in your version of node?

Comment: What versions/OSs are you using?

Comment: MacOSX 10.X and debian (latest 2 releases) depending on the machine in question (Jenkins, build, laptop, etc...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, node builds in only a reduced set of ICU data (English only) due to file size.

If you're already building node manually, if you `./configure --with-intl=full-icu` you will get the full ICU data set built-in. You can also use `--with-intl=system-icu` to have node use the OS ICU data.

If you're installing from some other (non-nodejs.org) source, such as an OS distribution repository, you will need to contact the maintainer of such binaries about providing builds with full-icu/system-icu.

One last option is to install the [`full-icu`](https://github.com/icu-project/full-icu-npm) module, which will make the full-icu data set available.

Comment: I've only tested the full-icu solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the top configuration?  I have node installed already and tried "node ./configure --with-intl=full-icu" but it's not working.

Comment: Node 13+ comes default with all locales supported by ICU. https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V13.md#2019-10-22-version-1300-current-bethgriggs

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Intl

> What is Intl?
>
> EcmaScript 402 describes the global Intl (short for
>   Internationalization) object and other related functions and
>   functionality.
>
> Node.js (or more properly, the v8 engine) uses ICU4C to implement this
>   Intl support in native C/C++. ICU's source is not included with Node's
>   source repository or source distributions.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

> The Intl object is the namespace for the ECMAScript
>   Internationalization API, which provides language sensitive string
>   comparison, number formatting, and date and time formatting. The
>   constructors for Collator, NumberFormat, and DateTimeFormat objects
>   are properties of the Intl object. This page documents these
>   properties as well as functionality common to the internationalization
>   constructors and other language sensitive functions.

I see that I don't have `Intl` in Node 5.12.0 but I do have it by default in Node 6.5.0.

It may have been added in 6.0.0: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.0.0/

> [[cdba9a6c02](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/cdba9a6c02)] -
>   src: add intl and icu configs to process.binding('config') (James M
>   Snell) [#6266](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6266)

Comment: I've got it in 4.5.0 so it does exist, but it is severely limited.