# Nodejs - RangeError: Value unit out of range for numberformat options property style

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use NumberFormat in NodeJS. It is working perfect for style "currency" but for style "unit" it is throwing the error:
**RangeError: Value unit out of range for numberformat options property style**

Here is my code:

```
Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "unit",
    unit: "kilometer-per-hour",
  }).format(71);
```

This is only happening in NodeJS. I tried the same code in browser console and it worked perfectly.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626119/where-does-intl-numberformat-support-come-from-in-node-js) will help.

Comment: languages are supported.. but the style "unit" is giving problem. Other styles like "currency", "decimal" are working fine.

Comment: It' working in JS but not in Node.js.

Comment: yes.. weird.. It is working here... https://jsfiddle.net/3bkg7z2r/

Comment: actually not all browser support it, In Safari it doesn't work too.

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/intl-numberformat check here supported browser list

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `polyfill` to support in all browser.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
  style: 'unit',
  unit: 'kilometer-per-hour',
});

console.log(formatter.format(7024));
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<!-- Polyfill Intl.NumberFormat, its dependencies & `en` locale data -->
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.NumberFormat,Intl.NumberFormat.~locale.en"></script>
</body>
</html>
```